# Cancel remaining stages in Jenkins if a prior stage condition is true

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a piece of groovy code in Jenkins that looks up for new software versions. If a new version is found, it downloads it; if there is no new versions available, the job stops.

I was wondering if there is a less messy way to stop all remaining stages if the condition that compare versions is true.

Here is my code:

```
pipeline {
    ...
    stages {
        ...
        stage('Compare Versions') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // these two variables are the ones that I use as a boolean.
                    if(CURRENT_VERSION == NEW_VERSION) {
                        echo "Current Version $CURRENT_VERSION, Available Version $NEW_VERSION"
                        echo 'The current version is already the latest one. Cancelling update.'
                        currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
                        error 'Cancelled Job'
                    }
                }
            }    
       
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with the code above is that it causes a train wreck of java errors due to the remaining stages still trying to unsuccessfully run. I would need to improve this code without any plugins.

Any assistance would be helpful.

Comment: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when

Comment: ^ would that mean that I have to add a 'when' condition for each stage?

Comment: Yes, for each stage

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it seems that I would be a pain from the maintenance perspective. If I were to change the variable, I would have to go back to each stage every time.